# Perforce client to automatically get the latest file

Tags: synchronization, perforce

Is there a way to set a perforce client so that it will always automatically sync the latest files when they are available in the depot?

Comment: This may not be exactly what you mean, but I have often set up simple "cron" or "Windows Scheduled Task" jobs which simply run 'p4 sync', and configured them to run once a minute. For example, I used such a task to maintain an internal web server for my company, where the automatic 'p4 sync' fetched internal web content into the web server's content directory. It took me about 2 hours to get it set up and operational, and it served the company for years with no issues.

Comment: Hi @BryanPendleton , yeah i understand that it could be done thru cronjobs, but i was looking more on whether is there an internal solution that comes directly from perforce itself. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Most VSC don't support that kind of feature because it is unpleasant to have files changed under you silently while you are working. The only use case are CI servers who often works by trigger or by polling.

Answer (score 1):

There is no out of the box functionality to do this, but you could write a script that checks the Perforce Server for changes to files in the client view and periodically syncs them.

This would have to run on the user's client machine.

Cheers,
Jen.